# Integration of H2O Deep Water w/GPU with DL frameworks

Tags: h2o

I want to study Deep Learning by using H2O Deep Water. I prefer using Docker images.

So I followed the instructions @ [H2O Deep Water installation](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater/blob/master/README.md). I installed Docker, the nvidia driver, nvidia-docker and the H2O w/GPU Docker Image and in the H2O Deep Water container I executed the .jar app. I'm able to use the Flow from a web browser. No errors.

The DIY instructions to build H2O Deep Water include a section to integrate either TensorFlow, MXnet or Caffe. I don't see this integration in the Docker installation section. Is this integration of a DL framework/software library not necessary for the Docker H2O Deep Water image?

I understand from the H2O slide presentations that with using TensorFlow, MXnet or Caffe the H2O DL models can have more hidden layers, using larger datasets with more features.

If this high-end functionality can only be obtained via mentioned DL frameworks / software libraries: How can I integrate a Docker H2O Deep Water container with for example a Docker TensorFlow container to obtain the same high-end DL functionality and capacity? 
Or is this type of Docker integration of H2O Deep Water with a DL software library not possible and do I have to build H2O Deep Water and the DL software library manually as described in the DIY section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is included in the docker image. You don't need to do any integrations yourself. You select the backend by setting the `backend` parameter to `tensorflow`, `mxnet`, or `caffe`.